# How to merge 2 fields based on id values and also ensure if the field is not available

Tags: dataweave

I am trying to merge to array fields based on ID condition. I made the below query:

The output which i am expecting in the CSV is:

```
ID,First Name,Last Name,Level,City,State
123,test,test1
456,test2,test3,level1,xyz,US
```

The output that I am getting now is:

```
ID,First Name,Last Name
123,test,test1
456,test2,test3,level1,xyz,US
```

If you notice, if the id value doesn't exist in the 1st record, the header is not populating in the csv even though the next subsequent records have value.
My requirement is to get the "Expected output" . If someone can please help it would be really useful.

Note: This issue is happening only when the first record doesn't match.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv header = true
var a = [ {
"ID": "123",
"First Name": "test",
"Last Name": "test1"
},
{
"ID": "456",
"First Name": "test2",
"Last Name": "test3"
}
]

var b = [ {
"ID": "222",
"Level": "level1",
"City": "xyz",
"State": "US"
},
{
"ID": "555",
"Level": "level1",
"City": "xyz",
"State": "US"
},
{
"ID": "456",
"Level": "level1",
"City": "xyz",
"State": "US"
}]
---
a map (aValue) ->
{
"ID": aValue."ID" ,
"First Name": aValue."First Name",
"Last Name": aValue."Last Name",

(b filter ( aValue."ID" contains $."ID") map (bValue) -> {
"Level": bValue."Level",
         "City" : bValue."City",
         "State" : bValue."State"
})
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The CSV writer defines the header by looking at the first item, so you'd need to make sure it has the complete key list. One way of doing that is defining an empty object for the second array and always merging it when there's no match. Notice I've modified your script to make use of out of the box joining functions:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
import * from dw::core::Objects

output application/csv header=true

var a = [ {
"ID": "123",
"First Name": "test",
"Last Name": "test1"
},
{
"ID": "456",
"First Name": "test2",
"Last Name": "test3"
}
]

var b = [ {
"ID": "222",
"Level": "level1",
"City": "xyz",
"State": "US"
},
{
"ID": "555",
"Level": "level1",
"City": "xyz",
"State": "US"
},
{
"ID": "456",
"Level": "level1",
"City": "xyz",
"State": "US"
}]

var emptyB = {
"Level": "",
"City": "",
"State": ""
}
---
leftJoin(a, b, (item) -> item.ID, (item) -> item.ID) 
    map ((item, index) -> item.l ++ ((item.r  default emptyB) - "ID"))
```